# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators, moderator-candidates

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://unix.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: There's a [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/) explaining the election in more detail, for those that haven't seen one before

Comment: Why was this [tweeted today](https://twitter.com/StackUnix/status/739281270941847552)? Why does it show as a featured on the main site when it is 5 years old? Should not the [tag:featured] tag be removed?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek what did you do in 2011?

Comment: @Jakuje: Because somebody added the `/featured` tag. Why can normal users do this?

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats actually, the system never removed it. Featured tags that are over 2 week old are automatically ignored by the CB, or at least that was before and then the latest edit just reseted the timer. Right now is different, after two weeks the tag is removed by Community.

Answer (score 5):

I figured I should post some sort of answer. The election is over; the winners were:

[image: Michael Mrozek]
[image: xenoterracide]
[image: mattdm]

Here's the complete OpenSTV output:

```
Unix and Linux Moderator Election 2011

OpenSTV version 1.6.1 (http://www.OpenSTV.org/)

Suggested donation for using OpenSTV for an election is $50. Please go to
http://www.OpenSTV.org/donate to donate via PayPal, Google Checkout, or
Amazon Payments.

Certified election reports are also available. Please go to
http://www.openstv.org/certified-reports for more information.

Loading ballots from file election-results.blt.
Ballot file contains 6 candidates and 54 ballots.
Ballot file contains 54 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Unix and Linux Moderator Election 2011 using Meek STV.
6 candidates running for 3 seats.

Round    Michael Mrozek    xenoterracide    phunehehe    mattdm       Tshepang    maxschlepzig    Exhausted    Surplus    Threshold
1        37.000000         8.000000         1.000000     4.000000     3.000000    1.000000        0.000000     23.499999  13.500001
Count of first choices. Candidate Michael Mrozek has reached the threshold and is elected.
2        13.500005         20.067565        2.905405     7.175675     6.810810    2.270270        1.270270     7.202704   13.182433
Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the threshold: Michael Mrozek, 0.364865. Candidate xenoterracide has reached the threshold and is elected.
3        13.793630         13.289569        4.820250     9.107686     8.408307    3.072247        1.508311     0.837353   13.122923
Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the threshold: Michael Mrozek, 0.356282 and xenoterracide, 0.656903.
4        14.038108         14.369332        4.820250     9.107686     8.408307                    3.256317     3.035598     12.685921
Count after eliminating maxschlepzig and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
5        14.160348         15.871956                     9.751404     8.751404                    5.464888     5.764746     12.133779
Count after eliminating phunehehe and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
6        12.511666        12.697122                      11.086877    10.086877                   7.617458     2.017516     11.595636
Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the threshold: Michael Mrozek, 0.305293 and xenoterracide, 0.502189.
7        11.694278        11.821160                      11.561103    10.561103                   8.362356     0.848305     11.409412
Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the threshold: Michael Mrozek, 0.282942 and xenoterracide, 0.458624. Candidate mattdm has reached the threshold and is elected.
Winners are Michael Mrozek, xenoterracide, and mattdm.
```

Answer (score -1):

Can we nominate other members?

Comment: No, you can only nominate yourself. If someone has nominated themselves, you can post a comment on their nomination expressing support (or not). If you want to prod someone into nominating, contact them in chat, mail, through this answer, or however you choose.

Comment: Haha.. Gilles.. I wanted to nomitate you.. matter of fact... As the highest ranking member, certainly one of the most active users and very knowledgeable on nix... please consider nominating yourself...